# jQuery - Confused between "Selectors" and strings passed as selectors

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that I wrote, which I personally found to be pretty nice. It takes a `<ul>` and it drops down the contents when clicked. But I am having a disconnect here in comprehension, and one I had to do what I feel is a 'dirty hack' to solve.

The problem is that I do not want the class `'sidebar-dropdown-open' to be so 'hardwired' in the plugin. However I discovered that there is a very stark difference between...

`$('.sidebar-dropdown-open')` and `'sidebar-dropdown-open` and even `'.sidebar-dropdown-open`.

I 'solved' this problem by including two different 'parameters' in my plugin, but I was wondering if someone might give me some insight as to how I could perform this better, and why this was behaving this way.

## wiring (document load)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('[data-role="sidebar-dropdown"]').drawer({
                    open: 'sidebar-dropdown-open',
                    css: '.sidebar-dropdown-open'
                });
        });
```

## html

```
<ul>
    <li class=" dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="pages/.." class="remote">Link Text</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="remote" href="pages/...">Link Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="remote" href="pages/...">Link Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="remote" href="pages/...">Link Text</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

## javascript

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.drawer = function (options) {
        // Create some defaults, extending them with any options that were provided
        var settings = $.extend({
            open: 'open',
            css: '.open'
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                // slide up all open dropdown menus
                $(settings.css).not($(this)).each(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass(settings.open);
                    // retrieve the appropriate menu item
                    var $menu = $(this).children(".dropdown-menu, .sidebar-dropdown-menu");
                    // slide down the one clicked on.
                    $menu.slideUp('fast');
                    $menu.removeClass('active');
                });


                // mark this menu as open
                $(this).addClass(settings.open);

                // retrieve the appropriate menu item
                var $menu = $(this).children(".dropdown-menu, .sidebar-dropdown-menu");
                // slide down the one clicked on.
                $menu.slideDown(100);
                $menu.addClass('active');
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

            }).on("mouseleave", function () {
                $(this).children(".dropdown-menu").hide().delay(300);
            });

        })
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This is likely a better question on http://programmer.stackexchange.com

Comment: I posted on programmer.stackexchange.com and was told to post it here instead.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Programmers is focused on [whiteboard/conceptual questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq), this is more to the technical side, and thus more appropriate for SO than Programmers. (Programmers mod here)

Comment: @JayBlanchard for the reference, question has been closed and rather heavily downvoted at Programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/178439/jquery-discrepency-between-classname-and-selectors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery selectors are styled exactly like css selectors making it very easy to learn for both designers and developers. In my opinion, you should just use one parameter and require it to be a classname, not a selector because if it were a selector, someone may think they can instead use an ID selector or a more complex selector there which would break your code.

Comment: I have tried that, but `$(settings.open)` doesn't work, even if `open` is declared as a classname.

Comment: Right, because you need to add the `"."`. `$("." + settings.open)`

Comment: While your fix works, and is much appreciated, this seems very unneccessary for a library that has been around for so very long. Is this really the only way to discriminate between a css class and anything else? I thought part of the 'convenience' of jQuery is that it treated everything correctly?

Comment: Thank you, by the way. That does fix the problem. It appears I have to ad-hoc a secondary option to just append the period within the actual plugin.

Comment: How is jQuery supposed to know that `$(settings.open)` is supposed to be selecting a class? or an ID? or a tag? jQuery is built around selecting elements in the same way that you select them in CSS. That's part of what made jQuery so popular because it makes it very easy to learn (how many people venture to js without knowing atleast some css?)

Comment: I think the disconnect for me comes from the inconsistency. For instance, when selecting a class, I need `$('.class')`, but when adding a class using `addClass`, I just use the name without the `.`. The inconsistency makes it confusing as to how jQuery is treating these.

Comment: Wait, this still doesn't make sense. You said to make it require a class Name, so if I require `.class`, then it doesn't work. Instead, if I accept only `class` and then **append** the `.`, it does work. So now I am confused again.

Comment: No, `".class"` is a selector, `"class"` would be the classname. (both are still strings, just to be clear)